# PHP Only allow alphanumerical Latin lowercase characters and dash

Tags: php, regex

I am using preg_match to validate a input text field that will be used for a subdomain name. I only want to allow alphanumerical Latin lowercase characters and dash no spaces or anything else.

Will the following be enough

```
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-]+$/', $instance)) {
     return true;
}
```

Comment: your regex also has uppercase (A-Z) and space ( ). You might also look for an online regex tester and see if your regex works for your needs.

Comment: The question is unclear: does the regex work for you? If it is not, when? Post concrete examples, what fails and what does not. You say no space, and you have put the space into the pattern. You mention lowercase, but place `[A-Z]` - why? That said, try `/^[a-z0-9-]+$/`, perhaps, that is what you are looking for.

Comment: A-Z was a mistake. Maybe I should have rephrased the question how do I make sure the following only allows alphanumerical Latin lower-case characters and dash

Comment: Ok, does my suggestion work for you then?

Comment: yes more or less but the dash probably should;d have been escaped. Kaspers answer seems to work perfectly

Comment: No, it does not need to be escaped, I will post my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The regex You are currently having is allowing a-z, A-Z 0-9 and spance and - (the \ is just for escaping)

So your regex would be something like this  (only allowing lowercase and -)

```
 if(preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/', $instance)) {
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: `-` does not need escaping if it's the last character in a group.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you have - `^[a-zA-Z0-9 \-]+$` - currently matches both upper- and lowercase Latin letters, Arabic digits, a space and a literal hyphen.

You say you do not want to allow any spaces or uppercase letters.

In this case, all you need to do it to remove them from the character class:

```
/^[a-z0-9-]+$/
```

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - the beginning of a string
- `[a-z0-9-]+` - 1 or more characters that are either lowercase Latin letters (`a-z`), or digits (`0-9`), or a hyphen (`-` at the end of the character class is almost always considered a literal in all regex flavors (but some weird ones))
- `$` - end of string.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX4nU7/1)